# How to make a turning lane without an intersection?

Tags: cities-skylines

I want to create a turning lane, as showed in the picture below. I want it to be a turning lane for one direction, not an intersection. That means, I want it not to affect the other direction in any way. Cars stop on intersections, when the traffic is full after the intersection. I don't want that. Is there any mod that could do this?
[image: Roundabout in Tabor, Czech Republic]
How to do this?

[image: Roundabout]
Here's what I have. If I add the highway entrace ramp, as you can see, it creates an intersection right after/before the roundabout. *Highlighted in red.* I want the connecting strip leading from bottom to the right to be only a turning lane, not an intersection, so it doesn't create the highlighted little lanes. If a truck turns on this lane, the ones behind it will stop, no matter how the traffic in front of the truck is, because there is an intersection. I want it to be a continuous lane for the people going south, and only a turning lane for people going east, without an intersection.

[image: I want dis!]
This is what I want to have.

Comment: just a clarification question, are you asking about the additional lane that is highlighted in red? or the entire construct?

Comment: Uh... Should specify that. I want the additional lane only. I have my roundabout, but if I add the lane, cars will always stop before the roundabout, because there is an intersection right before it. I'll add screens.

Comment: Yes, i will remove my answer for now and adjust it after you fixed up the question.

Comment: Can't you use a highway entrance/exit ramp lane for this?

Comment: Edited my question. I hope it's more clear. I might create another image showing what I want to achiev exactly.

Comment: for a moment I thought the top image was a modded version of the game

Comment: I think it's worth noting that you have the opposite problem at the end of the turn lane - cars may turn left across the three lane road, halting everyone heading east.

Comment: That would be a problem, yes. However, I use Traffic ++ to change output directions of lanes, so that you can turn only right. :)
@nickson104 That would be quite lovely but sadly it is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the two way roads, the game's behavior is always to create an intersection like you're seeing, as it assumes that you want traffic from both directions to be able to enter/leave the intersecting road.

So instead of using a single two way road, you can get fairly close to what you're looking to make by using two one way roads as a sort of DIY avenue. It ends up looking something like this:

[image: DIY Avenue]

At this point, you could add your one way 'turning lane' to the one way road that you want it for. It would still create an intersection, but since both roads are one way it would work essentially like what you're looking for, with cars peeling off out of the right lane to avoid the roundabout. You can make sure this happens by using a highway on-ramp for the turn lane: cars try to choose the fastest routes and on-ramps have higher speeds than regular roads.

Edit: here's one that I built:

[image: Roundabout with turn lane]

Note that I was using the [Sharp Junction Angles](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=553184329&searchtext=) mod.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks mate, it's not exactly what I was looking for, but you know that, and it solves my problem anyway. Still, if you'd encounter a mod that would make actual turning lanes possible, please let me know. For now this is the solution and it is a great approach actually. :)

Comment: I've heard mods like what you want discussed more than once, but nothing ever seems to have come from them. As it is, I'm not certain that it's possible without Colossal Order doing some programming of their own to allow for it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is limit the type of road that exists when the "off ramps", or rather single direction lanes come into play.

Traffic light intersections only exist when specific roads are used like 4 lane roads or more, or multi directional roads.

I recommend this video that goes into detail about which types of roads create which types of intersections, lights, and traffic:

Using a combination of these techniques you should be able to create a lane that does not use a traffic light, but it might have to be a different type of road than you initially wanted.

Comment: If possible, please summarize the techniques in the video. If the video is removed, this post is rather worthless.

Comment: This does not exactly answer my question, as I want to get rid of not only the traffic lights, but the whole intersetion, which is, I believe, not possible without modding, but I might try to summarize it and add it here, as it might help other reades. How do I do that? Do I edit this answer or add a new one?

Comment: There's more than one reason to put an incomplete answer, one of which is to spur other users to provide a proper answer, lest your question ends up here forever - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered